# \newgeometry for twoside report

Tags: header-footer, geometry, double-sided

I have my `preload.tex` as

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[math]{iwona} %nice font
\usepackage[top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%%
%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
%%
%%
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fitallincludepdf[2][]{%
    \AM@findfile{#2}%
    \setkeys{pdfpages}{#1}%
    \expandafter\AM@readlist\expandafter{\AM@pagestemp}%
    \@for\xxx:=\AM@pagelist\do{%
        \edef\AM@tmp{[\unexpanded{#1},
        width =0.99\textwidth, 
        height=0.99\textheight,
        keepaspectratio,pages=\xxx]}%
        \expandafter\includepdf\AM@tmp{#2}%
    }}%
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%      - HYPERREF -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%      -    QR    -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{qrcode}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    contents={exmaple-image},
    pages=some,
    placement=bottom,
    color=black,
    scale=1,
    opacity=0.5,
    hshift=9cm,
    vshift=0.2cm
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% background - go to back
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\AM@AddToShipoutPicture{\AddToShipoutPictureFG*}
\makeatother
%\NoBgThispage
%\BgThispage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%       - License -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
    type={CC},
    modifier={by-nc-nd},
    version={4.0}
]{doclicense}
%%
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%      - By Topic -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false,
    bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number freestyle={ Q\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter} }
    ]{question}{ O{}mo }{
%   lowerbox=ignored, %invisible/ignored
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title=\thetcbcounter: #2,
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3 }}}{},
    #1
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%       -   OWN   -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\fakesection}[1]{%
    \par\refstepcounter{section}% Increase section counter
    \sectionmark{#1}% Add section mark (header)
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}% Add section to ToC
    % Add more content here, if needed.
}%%
%%
%%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

which is loaded to

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, UTF8, scheme=plain, twoside]{ctexart}
\input{../../preload2.tex}
%%
\begin{document}
%%
\fancyhead[L]{LogoName}
\fancyhead[R]{Page~\thepage\ of~\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot[L]{myhyperlink}
\fancyfoot[CO]{center for odd}
\fancyfoot[CE]{center for even}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newgeometry{left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
\lipsum[7]
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{TOC} % Add section to ToC
\tableofcontents
\vspace*{\fill}
\doclicenseImage
%%
%%
%%
%%
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\normalsize
\newgeometry{top=1cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,headsep=0.3cm}
\setlength{\topskip}{0cm}
%%
%%
\lipsum[7]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Begin
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\lipsum[20-100]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%       -   End   -     %%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\NoBgThispage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\mbox{}
\vfill
\huge{[This page is intentionally left blank.]
\vfill
%%
%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

**Two problems here:**

First, the `left` and `right` margins are very odd to me. I don't know what length they have used.
How do I enforce the setting from `\newgeometry{}` so I have the same left and right margin as desired?
I only use twoside, so that I can have different footers for odd and even pages.
[image]
[image]

Secondly, where are the `extra` pages at the end from???
[image]

Comment: I take it you didn't write the preload.tex.  Can you modify it?  OTOH, if it is required for publication or a thesis, I wouldn't attempt to change the defaults either.  And \newgeometry typically adds pages; use \setgeometry instead.

Comment: No, I "wrote" it for my self, it's a compilation of the stuff that I use. Yes, we can MODIFY it as we like. I just dont really get why `\newgeometry` didn't work. I will try `\setgeometry`

Comment: @JohnKormylo `\setgeometry` is not defined ....

Comment: Oops, just `\geometry` (page 4 of geometry manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo But that can only be used in `preamble`, which would not allow me to change margins later...

Comment: Once you load fancyhdr, the width of the header and footer is fixed.  There is an automatic \clearpage (or \cleardoublepage) at \newgeometry and \restoregeometry and possibly \end{document}.

Comment: If `fancyhdr` should recalculate the width of header and footer, use one of the commands `\fancyhfoffset`, `\fancyheadoffset` or `\fancyfootoffset` in the preamble, eg. `\fancyheadoffset{0pt}`.

Comment: Why do you set `topskip` to `0pt`? Removing this line seems to solve the second issue.